# Tclsh can support user only type partial tcl command, but Tcl script not support

Tags: tcl

We implemented some tcl commands, if we type only part of the command at Tcl> prompt in tcl shell interactive mode, the tcl shell can recognize the command. But if we put the same partial command in tcl script file, then source the script from tcl shell, unknown command will be reported. And the whole command in tcl sript can be recognized.

How can we make source tcl script behavior same as shell interactive mode? We expect when source tcl script, partial command can also be reconginzed.

Please see following sample.

1. Partial command can be recognized in shell interactive mode.

> ```
> Tcl> my_prove
> Info: proving started
> Info: ....
> Info: ....
>
> Tcl> my_pro
> Info: proving started
> Info: ....
> Info: ....
> ```

2. Partial command cannot be recognized when source run.tcl script.

a) run.tcl

> ```
>    setup_design
>    my_prove
>    my_pro
> ```

b) source the script run.tcl

> ```
> Tcl> source run.tcl
> $inside source$$> setup_desgin
>     Design setup...
>     Done
> $inside source$$> my_prove
>     Info: proving started
>     Info: ....
>     Info: ....
> $inside source$$> ::unknown my_pro
>     invalid command name "my_pro"
> ```

Comment: IMO, you should not do this, script files should contain the full command/option names. But, in an interactive tclsh session, examine the [`unknown`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/unknown.htm) proc (with `info body unknown`), and copy that implementation (or the relevant parts of it)  into your tcl scripts/libraries.

Comment: Thanks, so it is recommended to use full command name in script file. It's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl implements partial command name expansion in the `unknown` procedure (along with numerous other things) and only turns it on in interactive mode. It's generally strongly recommended to use full command names in your scripts; that's far more likely to be reliable.

If you want to enable it, *which I don't think you should,* do this (this version uses `tailcall` so needs at least Tcl 8.6):

```tcl
rename unknown _standard_unknown
proc unknown args {
    set cmd [lindex $args 0]
    set matches [uplevel 1 [list info commands $cmd*]]
    # If there is a unique match, use it
    if {[llength $matches] == 1} {
        lset args 0 [lindex $matches 0]
        tailcall {*}$args
    }
    tailcall _standard_unknown {*}$args
}
```

In theory, you can also set the `tcl_interactive` global to any true value (e.g., `1`) to enable the expansion. However, there may be other unwanted behaviours as well enabled by doing that; Tcl makes no guarantees on that front.

Comment: Thanks Donal! Then I think use full name in script is ok if it will be more reliable.